# Use CoreImage to get color counts / dominant (not average)?

Tags: ios, core-image

It's trivial to get the average color of an image, using CI, so

```
filter = CIFilter(
  name: "CIAreaAverage",
  parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: image, kCIInputExtentKey: whole thing])
```

But what if you want the most-used color?

(Or ideally the top few most-used?)

Please note that this is trivial to do by hand. (Color-thief say, try it in your browser lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief )

This question is specifically about **Core Image**, thanks.

It would seem that Apple use dominant (not average) color in a couple of their own iOS apps, so, it would seem there's a CI way?

Again, note that this question is specifically about **Core Image**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [CIAreaHistogram](https://cifilter.io/CIAreaHistogram/) filter should do the trick. The highest values in the histogram correspond to the most prominent colors in the input image.

Or, new in iOS 13, you can also use the [CIKMeans](https://cifilter.io/CIKMeans/) filter to "create a palette of the most common colors found in the image".

Comment: Are there examples of the use of the CIKMeans and the related CIPalettize, CIPaletteCentroid  filters? I'm mystified by the CIKMeans error "Mean seeds should be passed as a K x 1 image.."